# Php, PDO query, fetch all returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm trying to get the results from a Select statement using fetchALL() but nothing is working for some reason. Here is a sample of the code:

```
$vars = array(':name' => $_POST['name'], ':id' => $_POST['id']);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE name=:name AND id=:id");

if($stmt->execute($vars)){
    if($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0){
        echo "Found";
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r($result);
    }else{
        echo "Not found";
    }
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

The statement executes successfully, and it finds one column, like it should, and it echos "Found", but the array comes up as empty, it just comes up as `array()` Everything executes well, it's just that fetch, or `fetchAll()` always returns empty. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you see if you run that SQL statement in the MySQL monitor? How many rows?

Comment: Assuming your query is returning just one row, `fetch_column()` is fetching it to extract the column data. When you then call `fetchAll()` the data has already been fetched and there's no more.

Comment: ^ You're totally right, I got it now lol, thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to fetchAll after fetchColumn.

[fetchColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

> Returns a single column from the **next** row of a result set or FALSE if
>   there are no more rows.

[fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

> PDOStatement::fetchAll() returns an array containing all of the
>   **remaining** rows in the result set.

So, you could rewrite it like this.

```
 if($result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "Found";
        print_r($result);
 }else{
        echo "Not found";
 }
```

Comment: This was it, I literally figured it out right after I posted the question too lol, but thanks for the help! And +1 for the right answer!